# SAX or DOM with XML?

Tags: sax

I have been trying to learn more about SAX but couldn't find anything that gives me more information about it. It points me to the DOM methods.

Is DOM the preferred way of working with XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

DOM and SAX are two fundamentally different tools to work with XML.

DOM is an in memory representation for XML files. You load the file completely into memory (e.g. using SAX) and then you can do a whole lot of stuff with DOM.

SAX is just a tool that generates events from an XML input. SAX is very fast, consumes little memory and really cannot do anything but do stream operations on XML files.

Choose your tool wisely based on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand when you say you can't find any information on SAX. Here are some high-quality sources of information that will help you get started in the right direction:

- First there's the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).
- Then there's [an online book on Elliotte Rusty Harold's site](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/).
- Then there are [some](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076282/java-xml/programming-xml-in-java--part-1.html) [old](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074279/java-xml/take-the-sting-out-of-sax.html) [articles](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076141/java-se/mapping-xml-to-java--part-1.html) on javaworld that are still helpful.

DOM creates a tree structure representing the document in memory, it has the lowest learning threshold but has trouble handling big documents.

SAX is event-driven and has some pitfalls that make it tricky to use (skipping reading the API documentation is not a good idea), but it allows the document to be processed as a stream so it can be used to process very large documents.

Comment: Expand your search beyond W3 Schools.